# Comparing types with Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm looking to do something like the following, but when I try to see if b == Test.self I get the error "Any class is not convertible to MirrorDisposition". How can I checked to see if a Type is equal to another type?

```
class Test {

}

var a = Test.self

var b : AnyClass = a

if(b == Test.self) {
    println("yes")
}
else {
    println("no")
}
```

Comment: let result = type(of: a) == type(of: b)

Comment: I copied your code into Playground (Swift 5) - it successfully launched and printed "yes". Probably the question is outdated, isn't it?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Use the "identical to" operator `===`:

```
if b === Test.self {
    print("yes")
}
else {
    print("no")
}
```

This works because the type of a class is itself a class object and can therefore
be compared with `===`.

It won't work with `struct`s. Perhaps someone has a better answer that works for
all Swift types.

Comment: TIL about a new operator :D Thanks.

Comment: Why it cannot be compared between `Any?` and `Any?` ? I had an error: `Binary operator === cannot be applied to two Any? operands`

Comment: @Kuba:  The `===` operator is only defined for instances of a *class.*

Comment: @Legonaftik: You are completely right, there is a `func == (t0: Any.Type?, t1: Any.Type?) -> Bool` operator now. I'll see if I can find out if that has been added.

Answer (score 40):

```
if b.isKindOfClass(Test) {
    println("yes")
} else {
    println("no")
}
```

**Edit: Swift 3**

```
if b.isKind(of: Test.self) {
    print("yes")
} else {
    print("no")
}
```

try it :)

Comment: thanks - this helped me solve some particularly painful EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors because the IS operator was returning false positives.

Comment: @Matt Bolt Oh. Cool :)

Comment: for some reason the ===  ("identical to") operator didn't work while checking UIAlertController while .isKindOfClass worked well

Comment: a Yeah... this is the way ;)

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to compare the class types, then you can simply use NSStringFromClass to compare the class names as below:

```
class Test {}

var a = Test.self
var b : AnyClass = a

if(NSStringFromClass(b) == NSStringFromClass(Test.self)) {
    println("yes")
} else {
    println("no")
}
```

If you want to find out or compare the type of an object, you can use "if ... is ... {}" syntax as code below:

```
class Test { }
class Testb { }

var a = Test.self
let b : AnyObject = Testb()

if(b is Test) {
    println("yes")
} else {
    println("no")
}
```

If you want to do object to object equality check with == operator, you can make your Test class conforms to Equatable protocol. This can be extended to both Struct and Class types in Swift as explained in this NSHipster article: http://nshipster.com/swift-comparison-protocols/.

You code then can be written as below, please note: this is object equality checking, so you cannot define b as AnyClass, you need to instead define as AnyObject.

```
class Test: Equatable { }

// MARK: Equatable
func ==(lhs: Test, rhs: Test) -> Bool {
    return ObjectIdentifier(lhs) == ObjectIdentifier(rhs)
}

var a = Test()
var b : AnyObject = a

if((b as Test) == a) {
    println("yes")
} else {
    println("no")
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To compare instances use

`type(of: instanceA) == type(of: instanceB)`